# Is it possible to get Page<> response using between date query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get a `Page<Transaction>` response for `Transaction` between 2 dates. Basically I want to merge these two methods:

`Page<Transaction> findAll(Pageable pageable);`

`List<Transaction> findByTransactionTimeBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, Pageable pageable);`

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, UUID> {

    @Override
    Page<Transaction> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    
    List<Transaction> findByTransactionTimeBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, Pageable limit);

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `findBy...()` methods will search across all records to find ones that match - it's _inherently_ "merged" with `findAll()`.

Comment: curious question - why do u wanna combine these two methods ?

Comment: Question is not exactly clear, but if i understand correctly, yes it's possible, just return Page, not List - `Page<Transaction> findByTransactionTimeBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, Pageable pageable);`